# How to convert a text string 20200821144500 into date and time format in r?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a date/time column saved like this 20200821144500. How do I convert it to date and time format?
I tried as.POSIXct('20200821144500',format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") which returned NA.
Am I using the wrong format or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct('20200821144500',format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main feature here is to tell which is first year month or day etc.. in the string. and to use HMS , because:

- hms, hm and ms usage is defunct, please use HMS, HM or MS instead.
  Deprecated in version '1.5.6'.

```
library(lubridate)

string <- "20200821144500"

parse_date_time(string, "ymd_HMS")

[1] "2020-08-21 14:45:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, based on `lubridate::ymd_hms`:

```r
lubridate::ymd_hms("20200821144500")  
  
#> [1] "2020-08-21 14:45:00 UTC"
```

Comment: At the same second. lol :-)

Comment: Perfect, @TarJae!

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `strptime` with right `format`:

```r
strptime(as.character(20200821144500),format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
#> [1] "2020-08-21 14:45:00 CEST"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>